# Очередь запросов на разные сервера

Tags: python, очередь, celery

У меня есть сервер бэка на `python` и несколько серверов бд:

```
           <-> db
-> backend <-> db
           <-> db
```

Сейчас используется один сервер бд, мне нужно распараллелить запросы на разные сервера. Это делается с помощью очереди:

```
                     <-> db
-> backend <-> queue <-> db
                     <-> db
```

В проекте уже реализована работа с `Celery` для других задач, и, мне кажется, здесь тоже нужно использовать именно его, но проблема в том, что я с ним ещё не работал.

Можете посоветовать доки/мануалы/код с решением подобной задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, была довольно глобальная ошибка в архитектуре этой идеи. Как решение, нужен был не `Celery` или другая очередь, а отдельный сервер-балансировщик, для чего нужно было перенаправить все запросы через `nginx` в другом контейнере.